# react doesn't allows to edit in node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, visual-studio-code, terminal

I tried to run npm start on the terminal but this error including with many errors came in the terminal.

> i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
> C:\adrosonics_main\KM\km_admin_portal_revamping (3)\km_admin_portal_revamping\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:133

I expect to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps.

1. Delete the node modules
2. Run `npm cache clean`
3. Run `npm install`
4. Lastly `npm start`